# How to show device's current location in Google Maps?

Tags: android, google-maps, gps

I am creating an application in Android like OLA cab. I want to show the cab's location on Google Maps, for this I need to read data from the cab's GPS device. I know how to get current location of my device, but my problem is how to get the location of the other GPS device?

Comment: Track the location > upload to the server > request to get  a location of a specific user > get the location from the server :)

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/a/24998876/1311951 
This will help in your question

Answer (score 0):

Each cab must update its current location to server periodically. When the user opens the apps the cabs locations must be retrieved from server and update it in google map.
For your requirement you have to make real time location update on both server and client side.